# How to register a device through node.js Bluemix push API

Tags: node.js, push, ibm-cloud

We are developing a mobile application. First, we put the registration option in mobile (Bluemix js Push API). But, for a security reason, we moved all (register device, push devicebyid,tag ..) options to node.js server. I use the node.js Bluemix Push API, but I didn't find a register device option there.

I installed:

```
npm install ibmbluemix
npm install ibmpush
```

I wrote the following function on the server side:

```
ibmpush.pushNotificationAll(JSON.parse(req.body),function(response){
         res.send(response);
     });

  ibmpush.pushNotificationDeviceIds(JSON.parse(req.body),function(response){
         res.send(response);
     });

 ibmpush.pushNotificationAll(JSON.parse(req.body),function(response){
         console.log("push sent successfully",response);
         res.send(response);
     });
```

Please help me register a device through the node.js Push API.

Comment: Thank u @Bill Wentworth

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using an MBaaS backend application, there is not currently a way to register a device through the Node.js Push API. 
You can find the javascript API documentation for Push here:

https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/mbaas-api/docs/JavaScript/IBMPushService.html

If you are using an IMF backend application, you can use the REST API to register a device.  You can find the IMF REST API documentation here:

https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfrestapi/imfswagger/docs#!/push/registerDevice_post_15

Comment: Provide additional information and possible code snippets instead of just links as they can change overtime.

Comment: Please give some example links @John

Comment: @Gopi as John stated there is currently no way to register push from node in MBaaS so there would be no example snippets